# Can I install windows 10 having bios serialnumber

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, windows-installation, system-recovery

I bought HP prodesk 400 g7. It comes with preinstalled windows 10 and recovery partition. Preinstalled version of windows has lot of bloatware installed. I would like to install fresh windows 10. I wonder if I can just download windows 10 from Microsoft page and it will activate itself. Windows Bios utility `wmic bios get serialnumber` reports that it has some key built int and I have recovery partition. Does it mean I can just delete windows 10 partition and install fresh windows from Internet? I'm asking because this is my company computer and I can not experiment with it. I must be sure that it will work.

Comment: Running a clean install of windows on top of your existing one should detect your key from motherboard metadata and recover it. EDIT: Corrected error. OEM keys are not recovered from FS.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: make a full disk image before starting. You'll be able to restore it if something goes wrong.

Comment: Why reinstall, just uninstall the bloatware>>>>https://www.pcdecrapifier.com/

Comment: Windows 10 automatically detects and activates.  If you want to avoid the process of downloading an ISO, you can just use Fresh Start, and choose not to keep anything. Running commands to retrieve the serial number of your device and/or running software to display the license key isn't required to reinstall and activate Windows 10.

Comment: I double @Moab opinion.  It is a PITA to uninstall bloatware.. but so it s a fresh install and the fresh install won't have custom goodies that you actually might want to keep.

Comment: @Ramhound why not post that as an answer? Because this is going to be the easiest solution that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @LPChip - Because I submitted that comment during a small downtime but I had been working for 10 hours straight, I also have submitted several (nearly a dozen answers) that have said similar statements.  I was feeling lazy and didn’t have the time to find a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If you signed in with a microsoft account, the license Is synced to your account. That means if you sign it in should automatically activate windows.

Comment: Yes, but also in hardware. With UEFI no Microsoft account is required.